# Bitdefender doesn't load My Bitdefender

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, bitdefender

I have just installed the Bitdefender Antivirus free edition on my pc( Win 7 Ultimate 64bit). Now, when I try to load My Bitdefender page, it doen't load, instead it shows that "You need to have java script enabled to view this page", why it shows so? It doesn't use any browser( as far as I can see), if it uses, I would give a try to enable javascript. What should I do now?
Another problem is it shows "LAST UPPDATED: Updating...", but there is no data usage.

I have [image: attached] a screen shot of the problems.

Comment: I am going to guess it uses IE to display web content, and you have JavaScript disabled, I can tell my the interface its going to display content from a web resource.  It also very clearly has Twitter and Facebook integration.

Comment: I just explained the problem.  Be sure IE is set to allow JavaScript content.  You are also not logged into your My Bitdefender account which might cause problems.  I wouldn't use that particular application.